# Clean up redirect URL in Mockito tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mockito, mockmvc

I have some Mockito tests which use MockMvc for controllers testing. 
Controllers are using `@ControllerAdvice` which includes `@ModelAttribute`. It is needed because there are few attributes needed by 90% of controllers. 
I clean up this information from redirect URLs by `ignoreDefaultModelOnRedirect` (it seems more efficient than adding RedirectAttributes parameters in all methods). 
I need to test redirectUrl. But in this URL I see url + redirect attributes. I don't want to check with them because it is not how production behavior looks like. 
Is there any way to pass `ignoreDefaultModelOnRedirect` to MockMvc?

== Edited

User go to greeting -> Redirected to greetingRedirected

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(Model model) {
        return "redirect:/greetingRedirected";
    }

}
```

Model enriched with `@ControllerAdvice` data

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GreetingControllerAdvice {

    @ModelAttribute("attr")
    public String getAttr() {
        return "ATTRIBUTE";
    }

}
```

And now start simple test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ApplicationTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        GreetingController greetingController = new GreetingController();
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(greetingController).setControllerAdvice(new GreetingControllerAdvice()).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void greeting() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/greeting"))
                .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/greetingRedirected"));
    }

}
```

As the consequence the result is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Redirected URL 
Expected :/greetingRedirected
Actual   :/greetingRedirected?attr=ATTRIBUTE
```

I can use SpringRunner of course and `@Autowire` MockMvc but MockitoRunner is faster (which is important for big project with thousands of tests).

I can get rid of `setControllerAdvice(...)` but it will make behavior much less similar to production behavior for most of the cases(because I have lots of tests which do not check on redirection behavior).

Finally I can split tests on "redirected tests" (with disabled advice) and "not redirected tests" but it will be quite silly. :)

So I'm asking if there is any simple way to tell MockMvc/Mockito that parameter `spring.mvc.ignore-default-model-on-redirect` is enabled and should behave like expected.

Comment: Hi! You might need to add a bit more code to help make the question clearer

Comment: @DavidRawson Yes. You're right. Done.